# docker ps - show image ID instead of name

Tags: docker, docker-compose, container-image

I display running containers using
`docker ps` command. There is an *IMAGE* column that shows **name** of the image that each container was created from. However in the meantime (while containers were running) I have rebuilt some images. The new images have the same names but different **ID**s. Now I'd like to check from which image specific container was run. I cannot deduce this information using only image **name**. I need image **ID**. Is there any possibility to display ID of the image that was used to run specific container?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can pass multiple container-ids to the docker inspect command and then use the --format to only get the values that you want.

```
docker inspect --format='{{.Id}} {{.Name}} {{.Image}}' $(docker ps -aq)
```

This will give you a list of the docker container Ids, names and image IDs that are being used for all of your containers.

```
asdf1234 /mydockercontainer sha256:abcd1234
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/

Comment: What if instead of image id, I want the name of the image being used by the containers?

Comment: Try this `docker inspect --format="{{.Config.Image}}" CONTAINER_NAME`

Answer (score 7):

I found that 
`docker inspect <container-id>` 
can be used for this purpose.
It displays an *image* field containing full hash.

Comment: `docker inspect <container-id> | grep Image | grep sha256`

Answer (score -7):

```
docker images
```

will show you the image names and their IDs