# How to find all image tags of a running Docker container?

Tags: linux, bash, docker, docker-container, docker-image

I have a bunch of Docker containers running on a server and I used the "latest" tag or no tag at all for all of them. Now I want to freeze the image versions, but I have no idea when I pulled these images, so I can't tell which version "latest" is referring to. `docker ps` is just showing me that the containers use the "latest" or no tag, like this:

```
# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
371d6675888b        node:latest            "npm start"              6 days ago          Up 2 hours                              project_xyz_1
ca5a75425a34        selenium/node-chrome   "/usr/bin/nohup go..."   6 days ago          Up 2 hours                              project_xyz-chrome_1
...
```

All images that I use are public images from the docker hub.

I thought maybe I could use the hex ID that docker ps shows for all the containers, but then I realized that the IDs are container IDs and not image IDs.

Is it maybe possible to get the image IDs/hashes of all running containers and then scan for all matching tags or something like that?

Docker version: 18.09.1, build 4c52b90

**Edit:**

So there have been some answers showing how to get the IDs (digests) of the images, but I need to somehow find the actual tags of those images.
After doing some research, I found that the docker hub has an API and that there is a way to get all tags for a given image and there is a way to get the digest for a given image+tag.  After looking at the API and a lot of examples from stackoverflow, I came up with this:
(It also includes the code required to get the digest of local images, taken form the answers below)

```
function getDigestByImageNameWithTag () {
    TARGET_IMAGE_NAME_WITH_TAG="$1" # works with and without tag
    docker image inspect --format '{{index .RepoDigests 0}}' "$TARGET_IMAGE_NAME_WITH_TAG" | cut -d '@' -f2
}

function getTagsByDigest () {
    TARGET_IMAGE_NAME="$1"
    TARGET_DIGEST="$2"

    # prepend the image name with "library/" if it doesn't contain a slash
    if [[ $TARGET_IMAGE_NAME != *"/"* ]]; then
        TARGET_IMAGE_NAME="library/$TARGET_IMAGE_NAME"
    fi

    # get authorization token for the given image name
    TOKEN=$(curl -s "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:$TARGET_IMAGE_NAME:pull" | jq -r .token)

    # find all tags for the given image name
    ALL_TAGS=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" https://index.docker.io/v2/$TARGET_IMAGE_NAME/tags/list | jq -r .tags[])

    # itate over all these tags
    for TAG in ${ALL_TAGS[@]}; do
        # get image digest
        DIGEST=$(curl -s -D - -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" https://index.docker.io/v2/$TARGET_IMAGE_NAME/manifests/$TAG | grep Docker-Content-Digest | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
        # if the tag matches the given digest
        if [[ $TARGET_DIGEST = $DIGEST ]]; then
            # "return" the tag
            echo "$TAG"
        fi
    done
}

function getContainerImageNames () {
    docker inspect $(docker ps  | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v ID) | jq .[].RepoTags | grep -v "\[" | grep -v "\]" | grep " " | cut -d '"' -f2 | cut -d '/' -f2-
}


# get all image names of all local containers
IMGS_WITH_TAG=$(getContainerImageNames)
# iterate of those image names
for IMAGE_NAME_WITH_TAG in ${IMGS_WITH_TAG[@]}; do
    # get the digest of the current iteration's IMAGE_NAME_WITH_TAG
    DIGEST=$(getDigestByImageNameWithTag $IMAGE_NAME_WITH_TAG)
    echo "TARGET_DIGEST: $DIGEST" 
    # get the raw image name without the tag
    IMAGE_NAME=$(echo "$IMAGE_NAME_WITH_TAG" | cut -d ':' -f1)
    # find all tags for this image that have the same digest
    MATCHING_TAGS=$(getTagsByDigest $IMAGE_NAME $DIGEST)
    echo "Image: $IMAGE_NAME_WITH_TAG"
    echo "Image digest: $IMAGE_NAME"
    echo "Image tags with same digest: "
    echo "$MATCHING_TAGS"
    echo "-----------------------------"
done
```

Unfortunately it seems to take forever to finish. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but that's the best thing I could come up with.

Any ideas on how to make this work properly?

Comment: `docker ps  | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v ID` is just `docker ps --format '{{.ID}}'`. Can you post what is a way to test your script and populate some docker images with some tags?

Comment: Well, you just need to have docker and jq installed and then you need to have at least one container started. For example: `docker run -d -t --name=test node:11 bash`. Tags with the same digest in that case would be 11.15.0-stretch, 11.15-stretch, 11-stretch, 11.15.0, 11.15, 11 right now from what I understand. So the script should return those..

Comment: because you comparing unnecessary tags, only compare those tags which you are using on the local system to save time, you can check my updated answer.

Comment: Wrong array usage. Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @Cyrus shellcheck didn't show any errors. It just warns about potentially unwanted splitting and globbing, which I don't think is an issue with this script.

Answer (score 8):

I think this is a better approach without inspecting the container, as docker ps already printing the docker image tag form which the container is created.

```
docker inspect $(docker ps  | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v ID) | jq .[].RepoTags
```

So first this gets the list of running containers, then inspect each image being used by running container and using `jq` get all repo tags of that image.

Here is the output.

[image: docker images tags and name]

**Updated:**

Here is you go using **skopeo** ,  you can do using API but will do the effort, so why if you have skopeo

You do not need to install `skopeo` you can run the container and then or remove once get the result, or you can install, script support both

```
running_container=$(docker ps  | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v ID) 
echo "running container: $running_container"
for image in $running_container
do
local_tag=$(echo "$image" | awk -F":" '{print $2}')
if [ -z $local_tag ]; then
# if tag is empty then tag is latest
local_tag="latest"
image="$image":"$local_tag"
fi
local_digest=$(docker inspect $image | jq '.[].RepoDigests[]' | awk -F"@" '{print $2}' | tr -d '"')
echo "Local digest is:" $local_digest
remote_digest=$(docker run --rm --env image=$image alexeiled/skopeo:latest ash -c "skopeo inspect docker://docker.io/$image" | jq '.Digest' | tr -d '"' )
echo $remote_digest 

# option2 install the skopeo on your local system
# remote_digest=$(skopeo inspect docker://docker.io/$image | jq '.Digest' | tr -d '"')
echo "Remote digest is : "$remote_digest

if [ "${local_digest}" == "${remote_digest}" ]; then
echo "local image is up to date with remote"
else
echo "Remote image is updated; please run docker pull $image"
fi
done
```

[image]

Comment: I like this one! but doing this do you have any guarantee that for example the `alpine:latest` currently running is the same than the `alpine:latest` currently available on the docker hub?

Comment: Hi @Nirekin, I just checked, please here you go

Comment: @Forivin did you try my answer?

Answer (score 4):

The RepoDigest field in the image inspect will have a sha256 reference if you pulled the image from a registry:

```
docker ps --format '{{.Image}}' | xargs \
  docker image inspect --format '{{if .RepoDigests}}{{index .RepoDigests 0}}{{end}}'
```

For a single image like `node:latest` on your host, that looks like:

```
docker image inspect --format '{{index .RepoDigests 0}}' node:latest
```

That digest cannot be changed by a push to the registry of the same tag name. When you pull the updated tag from the registry, you will see this digest update.

Comment: Okay, so I would have a digest then, but I would like to have something like `node:10.7.3` instead of `node@sha256:0aec4c38431c386877888c612a9340b1132bbeb4dc4af5b5ff54b9310d48e5a1` because with the latter I would have no idea if I had to update when vulnerabilities in my version are found.

Comment: @Forivin You don't have this information locally. You have only pulled latest which points to a sha256 that is static. All of the other tags are on the registry server, and it would take some work to query each tag remotely and see what repo digest it uses, especially factoring for multi-arch images and tags that may be updated.

Comment: @Forivin if a repo uses semver, then the best action is to specify the broadest dependency appropriate for your app, e.g. `node:10` instead of `node:10.7.3`, and then periodically pull new images and redeploy your containers.

Comment: But it should be possible to retrieve the information using the docker hub API right? I know that I can use https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/node/tags/?page=1 etc to get some information about all the possible tags. It's just missing the digest information.

Comment: @Forivin possible: yes. Trivial: no.

Comment: Okay, I tried to do this now, but it doesn't seem to work or it just takes forever. Would you mind taking a look at the Code I've added to the question?

Answer (score 0):

The docker inspect command can be used for this.
You can take a look at the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54075889/8113039

Comment: This would only get me the image IDs. I would also need a way to get the tags given the extracted image IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Docker images and containers are identified by an ID and for a running container you can get the Id of its image and then pull the image corresponding to the given ID.

First you need to use `docker inspect` on all your running containers in order to get the `sha256` Id the image on which the container is based.

`docker inspect` returns the image ID under `"Image"` :

```
{
  "Id": "6de053a2afa4499471c5e5c2afe0b0d83c9c7e50fc7e687fb63a7ebfd2bff320",
  ...
  },
  "Image": "sha256:26eb6780e26887a6838684a549562c0404fd85c55f71e0af6c79a4da5505d2a7",
  ....
}
```

Then you simply have to pull those images by digest (immutable identifier)

```
$ docker pull node@sha256:the-image-digest-here
```

or

```
$ docker pull node@sha256:26eb6780e26887a6838684a549562c0404fd85c55f71e0af6c79a4da5505d2a7
```

If you are lucky images corresponding to those digests are still available into the docker hub.

After that, is you are still facing `latest` images I will suggest you to rename those images with a proper name and tag and pull them in your own docker hub repository to be able to use them directly...