# Get the image name from a running or stopped container on docker

Tags: docker

If I have a stopped or running container, how can I know what is the image that is used to run this container. I am on windows 10, if at all that is needed.

[image: All container list]

I guess this is something trivial, but could not figure out. Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find all image tags of a running Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56646899/how-to-find-all-image-tags-of-a-running-docker-container), for stop image you can just need to add `-a` docker inspect `$(docker ps -a  | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v ID) | jq .[].RepoTags`

Comment: @Adiii, Thank you. I could get the info using docker inspect. But in your command, what is awk? I get 'awk' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. Am I missing something?

Comment: oh seems like you are using window. can you try this `docker inspect --format="{{.Config.Image}}" $(docker ps -aq)`

Comment: I get unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -aq). If I remove a, then I get unknown shorthand flag: 'q' in -q)

Comment: I am not sure how to work with subshell in window, can you try this with gitbash or `docker inspect --format="{{.Config.Image}}" \`docker ps -aq\`` or one way is to get ID of stop container and then run `docker inspect --format="{{.Config.Image}}"  CONTAINER_ID`