# Docker image used in container is not listed using docker image ls

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I'm deploying a cluster using Docker Swarm with the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  # Other services...

  # Workers
  worker:
    image: "jwaresolutions/big-data-cluster:0.4.3-survival"
    # Other settings...
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.role==worker
        # One replica per node
        max_replicas_per_node: 1
      # Deploy N containers for this service
      replicas: 3
    hostname: "{{.Node.Hostname}}"

volumes:
  # ...

networks:
  # ...
```

When I run the command `docker container ls` in all the replicas, It's showing the correct image `jwaresolutions/big-data-cluster:0.4.3-survival`:

```bash
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                            COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
1efffa6027a5        jwaresolutions/big-data-cluster:0.4.3-survival   "bash -c '/home/big_…"   17 hours ago        Up 17 hours                             big-data-docker_worker.1.0l4ggu4mne9m040nih7jy9x4s
```

But then I run the command `docker image ls` it's listing the following images:

```bash
REPOSITORY                        TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
jwaresolutions/big-data-cluster   <none>              caceaacc4909        5 weeks ago         4.65GB
jwaresolutions/big-data-cluster   <none>              ebee0452faeb        6 weeks ago         4.65GB
jwaresolutions/big-data-cluster   <none>              0aa947baa686        8 months ago        4.63GB
jwaresolutions/big-data-cluster   <none>              458e5ceb82b9        8 months ago        4.51GB
jwaresolutions/big-data-cluster   <none>              4a01dd36775f        10 months ago       4.49GB
jwaresolutions/big-data-cluster   0.4                 3407e263e81e        11 months ago       4.49GB
jwaresolutions/big-data-cluster   0.3-survival        25e167ef146e        15 months ago       3.86GB
jwaresolutions/big-data-cluster   <none>              bbc920dfb2dd        22 months ago       3.67GB
jwaresolutions/big-data-cluster   <none>              09f57a9dde60        2 years ago         3.67GB
jwaresolutions/big-data-cluster   <none>              c147ee54ee82        2 years ago         3.12GB
```

Why is not listed the image with tag `:0.4.3-survival`? Is there a way to inspect the image object being used by the container (specifically, I wanted to get the `digest` field as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33511811/7058363))?

Answer (score 0):

So to answer your last question
`docker ps -a`
Lists
`CONTAINER ID   IMAGE  COMMAND   CREATED STATUS  PORTS NAMES`
In its output. Looking around it seems like if a tag is specified when the container is built, it should be included in the `IMAGE` output of the container.

Mostly referring to this answer as it seems like others have some scripts that may be helpful as well

[How to find all image tags of a running Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56646899/7960407)

Comment: Hi, first of all, thank you for your reply! The problem is that I want to inspect the image, not to know which image is being used by the container (that information I already get with the `docker container ls` command). Specifically, I wanted to get the `digest` field as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33511811/7058363), but since it doesn't exist as a docker image on my machine, I can't inspect it. I already edited the question to avoid confusion :D